# Cannot install preload from the Terminal

Tags: installation, apt

I am an ubuntu novice. I cannot download preload from the terminal. When I input:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

It gives me this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package preload
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I what you said, it updated a few packages fine, but still gives me the same error after trying to get preload again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu are you running? I'm going to assume 12.04 for this answer.

If you're on a VPS, it may be that your hosting provider has different repositories than the standard Ubuntu ones.

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` to ensure you have a Universe repository configured, e.g., you have the following lines uncommented:

```
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

It could also be you hit a bad mirror, transient network or DNS issue, though those would most likely go away with a `sudo apt-get update`.

And after any changes, you'll need to update again.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, thanks to your answer. In the sources.list folder the lines beginning with 'deb' were present, but the lines with deb-src were not. I put them in and then I updated, and all is well. Thanks.